# Is there a realm browser for Linux?

Tags: android, linux, database, realm

I would like to browse a realm database using a browser. I'm a Linux user and I know the realm browser is only for MacOS. I also have knowledge about Stetho by Facebook and I read about this project https://github.com/uPhyca/stetho-realm too. However I don't want to add unnecessary libraries in my project and I install Google Chrome to browse a database, this is odd for me. So, do you know if there's a realm browser for Linux?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *I don't want to add unnecessary libraries in my project* Just use debugCompile for stetho

Comment: this comment must be an accepted answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am happy to say that my previous answer is now obsolete. Realm Studio (https://realm.io/products/realm-studio/) supports Linux, macOS and Windows.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to read the `.realm` file if it is encrypted? I tried loading some `.realm` files, but Realm Studio keeps saying "Either this is not a Realm file or it's encrypted" message. I guess there is no way since it is encrypted, right? I could be wrong though.

Comment: @warfreak92 Encryption is supported and you should get a dialog box where you can type in your key. If it doesn't work, please file a bug at https://github.com/realm/realm-studio/

Answer (score 2):

Download [Realm Studio for Mac, Linux and Windows](https://docs.realm.io/sync/realm-studio#download-the-latest-version)

```
curl https://studio-releases.realm.io/latest/download/linux-appimage -o realm-studio-3.x.x.AppImage
```

Mark it as an executable

```
chmod +x realm-studio-3.x.x.AppImage
```

And run it

```
./realm-studio-3.x.x.AppImage
```

Answer (score 0):

Get all versions from here.

Windows, Mac, Ubuntu

https://github.com/realm/realm-studio/releases