# How to read .realm database file in Windows

Tags: android, realm

I am facing a issue to read `.realm` database file in Windows. To read that I need to use again and again mac system.

Comment: @Tim Castelijns, no i want to read that in window not in linux..

Comment: Yes. I can read. I suggest you click on the link and read what is said there.

Comment: Yes i read but its not give satisfy answer. They say that no Realm Browser for Linux nor Windows but one of my colleague in my previous company use google chrome to read .realm database with a add-on which i don't know. I am trying to contact him but not reach to connect so i post here my question.

Comment: The "add on" you speak of is also mentioned there although it is in the question. it's called stetho-realm

Comment: No there is no way

Answer (score 2):

There is third party's Stetho Realm plugin https://github.com/uPhyca/stetho-realm, Stetho is Android debugging bridge developed by Facebook. It also let you be able to see the Realm's data on your devices.

Comment: thanks but i want to read .realm database file in window..  I heard that we read that with google chrome add-on but not confident.

Answer (score 1):

Urfortunately there is no direct way to open realm file in Windows . To view a realm file in windows we have use a debug bridge (STETHO)  build by Facebook @ http://facebook.github.io/stetho/  and  realm module for stetho build by uPhyca, Inc. @ https://github.com/uPhyca/stetho-realm .

Steps to be taken :

1) Add Stetho dependency :  **compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.3.1**'

2) Add Realm Module to Steltho : **compile 'com.uphyca:stetho_realm:0.9.0'**

3) Intialize Steltho like :

```
 **Stetho.initialize(
                Stetho.newInitializerBuilder(this)
                        .enableDumpapp(Stetho.defaultDumperPluginsProvider(this))
                        .enableWebKitInspector(RealmInspectorModulesProvider.builder(this).build())
                        .build());**
```

4) **Run your application with usb debugging .**

5) Open Chrome and type : **chrome://inspect** which will in return open up a screen which shows your connected device .

6) Click on inspect below your device name .

7) Seperate dialog will be open which contains all your device device internals .

8) Click on the Resources tab which contains a option name as Web Sql under which you can find you realm database .

You can refer from sample given at :  https://github.com/uPhyca/stetho-realm

Comment: Thanks its really helpfull.

Comment: @ChiragArora this answer is essentially the same as the other 2 answers combined. Why is this one helpful but the others aren't? This answer gives no new information. You even said you were looking for something else than stetho

Comment: actually these steps helps me to know better

Comment: @ChiragArora .. these steps are also explained in the links in the question/answer I gave you in the duplicate suggestion (which are the same links as in this answer). But then you said it was not satisfying for you.

Comment: guys use this. .https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/studio/install/

Answer (score 0):

Basically the same answer as in [Is there a realm browser for Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38917661/is-there-a-realm-browser-for-linux). Currently, the Realm Browser is only supporting Mac OS X, and we do not have a Windows version yet.